# Easily update the query string with a link

Tags: params, querystring

I'm working on a site with some filters that result in a page with a URL similar to this:
`domain.com/led-products?series=67&efficacy=1000to5000&lumens=over150`

That results page contains buttons/links like so:

`[Series Name x]
 [1,000 to 5,000 Efficacy x]
 [Over 150 Lumens x]`

Clicking on one of those would remove that filter. Let's say a user clicks on Series Name to remove that filter, the resulting URL would then be: `domain.com/led-products?efficacy=1000to5000&lumens=over150`

My problem is that I have no idea how to get that filter/parameter removal functionality in Craft. Does this require a JS solution?

I've played around with something [like this](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/2484/256) and can't seem to get it to work for my needs.

Help?

Comment: Are you trying to do this with javascript, or just reload the page with the modified query string?

Comment: Honestly, whatever is going to be easiest. I'm totally fine with reloading the page with the modified query string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this should be a working code example:

```
{% set queryParams = craft.app.request.queryParams %}
{% for key, value in queryParams %}
  {% set url = siteUrl ~ craft.app.request.fullPath %}
  {% set arr = queryParams | filter((v, k) => k != key) %}
  {% if arr|length > 0 %} 
    {% set url = url ~ '?' ~ arr|url_encode %}
  {% endif %}
  <a href="{{url}}">{{key}} {{value}} x</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Line by line:

Create an array based on the current [request parameters](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-web-request.html):

```
{% set queryParams = craft.app.request.queryParams %}
```

Loop through the array and get the key/value pair:

```
{% for key, value in queryParams %}
```

While inside the loop, get the URL that we want to modify, minus the request params:

```
{% set url = siteUrl ~ craft.app.request.fullPath %}
```

[Filter a local copy of the array](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/filter.html) to remove the current key:

```
{% set arr = queryParams | filter((v, k) => k != key) %}
```

If there are any parameters left, modify the URL we previously set with the remaining parameters:

```
{% if arr|length > 0 %} 
  {% set url = url ~ '?' ~ arr|url_encode %}
{% endif %}
```

Output the link that will load the page without the current parameter.

```
<a href="{{url}}">{{key}} {{value}} x</a>
```

I would probably do this in a macro to keep the template code a bit cleaner and easy to read.

Comment: THANK YOU!! This worked great! There's one tiny thing I had a question on: `p=page-slug` is added to the URL. I get why and it's not critical at all, but is there a way to remove that at all? Again, no biggie!

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure, I didn't see that when I was testing this out. But the filter function does accept multiple conditions so this might work: {% set arr = queryParams | filter((v, k) => k != key and k != 'p') %}